# Cocos2d v3: Physics collision begin selector called but with nil parameters

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

Just as the title suggests. The selector ccPhysicsCollisionBegin is being called with the right node type names but the passed nodes in the parameters are both nil. Any reason for this?

Thank You

Comment: Well.. can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! I found out what the problem was. If a node inherits from **CCNode** and tries to define a physics body without using the property but directly through the ivar **_physicsBody**, it would result in **_physicsBody.node** not being set. When the **ccPhysicsCollisionBegin** is called, the parameters are nil even though the Chipmunk bodies are there.

To avoid this, one must assign a physics body through the property instead of the ivar (which should be private).

You can check out the original thread from the Cocos2d-iphone forum here:
http://forum.cocos2d-iphone.org/t/cocos2d-3-0-physics-collision-begin-selector-called-with-nil-parameters/13316